# Object pool instantiating and removing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created an object pool for every instantiated prefab. I have 2 questions

1. How can I optimize the deletion of prefabs from object pool and re-add the removed one to the pool? The game features three types of platforms: normal, double jump, and broken. The broken platform collapses when the player jumps on it. However, my code does not remove the prefabs fast enough from my pool, causing the prefab count to continuously increase. Although it deletes the platforms, it does so slowly, which could cause problems if the player plays for an extended period of time. Additionally, the code does not remove all of the platforms, leaving some of them randomly. The platforms should be removed in the order the player jumps on them, but they are deleted slowly and some of them remain behind. What changes should i do?

This is the full script of my ObjectPool code:

```cs
public class ObjectPool : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;

    [Header("General Values")]
  
    public float currentBlockY;
    public float currentBlockX;
    public float disBeforeSpawnBlock = 10f;
    public float minDisBetweenBlocks;
    public float maxDisBetweenBlocks;
    public float minInsOffsetX;
    public float maxInsOffsetX;
    public float brokenMinOffsetX;
    public float brokenMaxOffsetX;
    public int initBlockLines = 10;
    public List<GameObject> normalBlockPool;
    public AnimController animeC1;

    [Header("Grass")]
    public GameObject grassPlatformPrefab;
    public List<Sprite> grassSpriteList;
    int grassSpriteCount;

    [Header("Slime")]
    public GameObject slimePlatformPrefab;

    [Header("Broken")]
    public GameObject brokenPlatform;
    public bool isBrokenPlatform = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitSpawnBlock();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(currentBlockY - player.transform.position.y < disBeforeSpawnBlock)
        {
            ContinueToSpawn();
        }
    }

    private void InitSpawnBlock()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < initBlockLines; i++)
        {
            GrassSpawner();
        }
    }

    private void ContinueToSpawn()
    {
        normalBlockPool[0].transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(minInsOffsetX, maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
        currentBlockY += Random.Range(minDisBetweenBlocks, maxDisBetweenBlocks);

        if(player.transform.position.y > 20 && Random.Range(0f, 2f) < 0.5f)
        {
            isBrokenPlatform = true;
            BrokenPlatformSpawner();

            if(isBrokenPlatform)
            {
                Vector2 blockPos = new Vector2(currentBlockX + Random.Range(brokenMinOffsetX, brokenMaxOffsetX), currentBlockY - Random.Range(1, 5));
                GameObject gO = Instantiate(grassPlatformPrefab, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
                gO.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = grassSpriteList[grassSpriteCount];
                gO.transform.SetParent(transform);
            }
        }
        else if(player.transform.position.y > 150 && Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.1f)
        {
            SlimeSpawner();   
        }
        else 
        {
            GrassSpawner();
        }
        GameObject temp = normalBlockPool[0];
        normalBlockPool.RemoveAt(0);
        normalBlockPool.Add(temp);
        temp.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void GrassSpawner()
    {
        grassSpriteCount = Random.Range(0, grassSpriteList.Count);
        Vector2 blockPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minInsOffsetX, maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
        currentBlockY += Random.Range(minDisBetweenBlocks, maxDisBetweenBlocks);

        GameObject gO = Instantiate(grassPlatformPrefab, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
        gO.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = grassSpriteList[grassSpriteCount];
        gO.transform.SetParent(transform);
        normalBlockPool.Add(gO);
    }

    private void SlimeSpawner()
    {
        Vector2 blockPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minInsOffsetX, maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
        currentBlockY += Random.Range(minDisBetweenBlocks, maxDisBetweenBlocks);

        GameObject gO = Instantiate(slimePlatformPrefab, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
        animeC1.SlimeAnimationOne();
        gO.transform.SetParent(transform);
        normalBlockPool.Add(gO);
    }

    private void BrokenPlatformSpawner()
    {
        Vector2 blockPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minInsOffsetX, maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
        currentBlockY += Random.Range(minDisBetweenBlocks, maxDisBetweenBlocks);

        GameObject gO = Instantiate(brokenPlatform, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
        gO.transform.SetParent(transform);
        normalBlockPool.Add(gO);
        gO.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

2. I am trying to create a one-way platform that has to break when the player touches only from above of it. But i can't do that and immediately after i touch that platform, it disappears.I want that "broken platform" to be destroyed or removed immediately after i touch it only from above. There may be some situations where i have to touch that breakable platform frombelow and it is also destroyed or removed. I used OnCollision method but that doesnt work because it is also apply code when i collide from below. Is there a way to do that so no destroying when i collide from below and only collide from above. This is my code:

```cs
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "BrokenPlatform")
        {
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>().gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

­­­­­⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: I can only see you `Instantiate` new objects .. there is no trace of an object pool in your code ...

Comment: For your second question checkout [Plattform Effector 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlatformEffector2D.html) which is basically exactly solving that

Comment: Have you taken a look at this PoC? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Pool.ObjectPool_1.html

Comment: Unity's own tut on pooling: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling#5ff8d015edbc2a002063971d